# Rollup: "Import of non-existent export" when importing function from Lodash

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash, rollupjs

I have a small library that's bundled as a UMD module using Rollup. I am trying to import a function from Lodash into my library, but I am getting an error.

I try to import the function like this:

```
import { partition } from 'lodash';
```

And I get this error:

```
(!) Import of non-existent export
src/main.js
1: import { partition } from 'lodash';
```

This is my rollup configuration:

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';

export default {
  input: 'src/main.js',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/browser-metrics.js',
    name: 'BrowserMetrics',
    format: 'umd'
  },
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**'
    })
  ]
};
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

install and use `lodash-es` module with es6 import/export functionality

```
npm install lodash-es
```

then

```
import { partition } from 'lodash-es';
```

or

```
import partition from 'lodash-es/partition';
```

Comment: Aha! `lodash-es` did the trick. Thanks! One other question: Even though I'm only importing `partition`, it looks like it's including all of lodash in my bundle. Is there a way to prevent this (tree shaking?)?

Comment: Hm, I might have been wrong. It is including a lot of stuff, but not *all* of lodash.

Comment: @JoeAttardi yes, if you use import like this `lodash-es/partition` it's will include the only partition in your bundle

Comment: Does this bundle the partition function in the bundle?  Saying it's external.

Answer (score 0):

better to still use 'lodash' and use [@rollup/plugin-commonjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-commonjs) and [babel-plugin-lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-lodash) to handle the 'cjs -> esm' convertion and tree-shaking.
there are so many popular NPM packages that export as 'cjs'. The work to switch from 'name' to 'name-es' on source code level would be huge and annoying.